# How to set password so i can connect to FTP on a Google Cloud Instance

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to set a password for my user so that I can access Proftpd ftp server of that Google VM instance.

sudo su and passwd does not work, even tho I get the message "password updated successfully"

When I connect to the ftp, I get incorrect password.

Anyone have a working solution to get an FTP server up on Google Cloud VM?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately password authentication in this manner is prohibited in the Google Cloud Platform for security purposes. You can use SSH keys to connect to an FTP server.

The following are the steps required to set up secure FTP with the client FileZilla on a Compute Engine instance:

1. Install the Cloud SDK and run 'gcloud init' to set up your environment if this is your first time running the tool.
2. Generate your SSH keys by connecting to your virtual machine using the gcloud compute ssh command:

gcloud compute ssh

ssh-keygen

If this is your first time connecting to the instance, you will be prompted to add a passphrase to protect your SSH keys. On subsequent connections, you are prompted to enter your passphrase if you used one.

3. Set up your SFTP client to use your SSH keys. These instructions use FileZilla, which runs on many different platforms. The process should be similar for other SFTP applications; refer to your application's documentation for how to configure SSH keys.

a. Download and install an SFTP client such as FileZilla (https://filezilla-project.org/).

b. Launch FileZilla.

c. To open the settings, go to Edit->Settings or FileZilla->Settings. Select the SFTP page.

d. Click Add keyfile.

e. Browse to the location where your SSH keys were generated. By default, this is in your Home directory (~/.ssh/).

Note: .ssh is a hidden directory. If it doesn't appear, you might need to enter ~/.ssh in the Location box. Also, you can press CTRL-H to toggle between showing and not showing hidden files. On Mac OS X, you can press command-shift-G and manually enter ~/.ssh.

a. Choose the private key (~/.ssh/google_compute_engine). FileZilla will prompt you to convert the key file into a supported format. Save this new private key in a secure location as it is unprotected. If you entered a passphrase when you created the key, you will need to enter it during the conversion process.

b. Close the settings dialog.

4. Connect to your virtual machine using your configured SFTP client.

a. In FileZilla, you must type the host name in the following format: sftp://

b. Specify the SFTP user as the same user that you used when you ran the 'gcloud compute ssh' command or as the root user. If you are connected to an instance using that command, you can determine the user based on the command-line prompt, which typically includes the user name. For example, if your command prompt is myName@myInstance:~$, then you would enter myName for the user. Also, you can find the user name by entering 'echo $USER'.

5. Upload files to your VM instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can authenticate via password after changing the PasswordAuthentication parameter from no to yes in /etc/ssh/sshd_config.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).